# Discord Embed function not working with API call

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm having issues with the embed function in discord.js where I am intermittently getting the error.

`DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction`

I've taken out a bunch of the code to try and identify the issue. The below code is a simplified version that is still causing me issues.

If I take the API Call out it works and the fact it is intermittent lends me to believe it might be something to do with how quick the API result which is then causing the embed to fail?

Any suggestions?

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
  console.log(interaction.commandName)

  const embed = new EmbedBuilder();
  embed.setColor('#0099ff')
  embed.setURL('https://top.gg/bot/951349733211930654')
  embed.setAuthor({ name: 'WINGMAN | Apex Legends', iconURL: 'https://apex-resources.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/apex-logo.png', url: 'https://top.gg/bot/951349733211930654' })


  id = interaction.id

  if (interaction.commandName === 'stats') {
    https.get(apilink, (resp) => {
      let data = '';
      // A chunk of data has been received.
      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });
      // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
      resp.on('end', () => {
        //console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        j_data = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(j_data)

        embed.setTitle("Header")
        embed.setDescription("**Status: ** ")

        interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
      });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `interaction` coming from?

Comment: I've added more code to the original question. Is that enough information?